# numpy Stacking 1D arrays into structured array

Tags: python, numpy

I'm running Numpy 1.6 in Python 2.7, and have some 1D arrays I'm getting from another module. I would like to take these arrays and pack them into a structured array so I can index the original 1D arrays by name. I am having trouble figuring out how to get the 1D arrays into a 2D array and make the dtype access the right data. My MWE is as follows:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> 
>>> x = np.random.randint(10,size=3)
>>> y = np.random.randint(10,size=3)
>>> z = np.random.randint(10,size=3)
>>> x
array([9, 4, 7])
>>> y
array([5, 8, 0])
>>> z
array([2, 3, 6])
>>> 
>>> w = np.array([x,y,z])
>>> w.dtype=[('x','i4'),('y','i4'),('z','i4')]
>>> w
array([[(9, 4, 7)],
       [(5, 8, 0)],
       [(2, 3, 6)]], 
      dtype=[('x', '<i4'), ('y', '<i4'), ('z', '<i4')])
>>> w['x']
array([[9],
       [5],
       [2]])
>>> 
>>> u = np.vstack((x,y,z))
>>> u.dtype=[('x','i4'),('y','i4'),('z','i4')]
>>> u
array([[(9, 4, 7)],
       [(5, 8, 0)],
       [(2, 3, 6)]],    
      dtype=[('x', '<i4'), ('y', '<i4'), ('z', '<i4')]) 

>>> u['x']
array([[9],
       [5],
       [2]])

>>> v = np.column_stack((x,y,z))
>>> v
array([[(9, 4, 7), (5, 8, 0), (2, 3, 6)]], 
      dtype=[('x', '<i4'), ('y', '<i4'), ('z', '<i4')])

>>> v.dtype=[('x','i4'),('y','i4'),('z','i4')]
>>> v['x']
array([[9, 5, 2]])
```

As you can see, while my original `x` array contains `[9,4,7]`, no way I've attempted to stack the arrays and then index by `'x'` returns the original `x` array. Is there a way to do this, or am I coming at it wrong?

Comment: Do you need to operate on the 2d array? Why not just use a dictionary?

Comment: I guess I just assumed it would be better to not mix data types and use ndarray since it supported dict-like indexing, but there's no real sound reasoning behind that.

Comment: To answer the first question, no, in this case I don't need to operate on the 2d array.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

One way to go is

```
wtype=np.dtype([('x',x.dtype),('y',y.dtype),('z',z.dtype)])
w=np.empty(len(x),dtype=wtype)
w['x']=x
w['y']=y
w['z']=z
```

Notice that the size of each number returned by randint depends on your platform, so instead of an int32, i.e. 'i4', on my machine I have an int64 which is 'i8'. This other way is more portable.

Comment: +1 This is actually the only way to get arrays with different dtypes into a single structured array.

Comment: Is the a way to do it when x, y, z, have different number of elements?

Answer (score 3):

You want to use [`np.column_stack`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.column_stack.html):

```
import numpy as np

x = np.random.randint(10,size=3)
y = np.random.randint(10,size=3)
z = np.random.randint(10,size=3)

w = np.column_stack((x, y, z))
w = w.ravel().view([('x', x.dtype), ('y', y.dtype), ('z', z.dtype)])

>>> w
array([(5, 1, 8), (8, 4, 9), (4, 2, 6)], 
      dtype=[('x', '<i4'), ('y', '<i4'), ('z', '<i4')])
>>> x
array([5, 8, 4])
>>> y
array([1, 4, 2])
>>> z
array([8, 9, 6])
>>> w['x']
array([5, 8, 4])
>>> w['y']
array([1, 4, 2])
>>> w['z']
array([8, 9, 6])
```

Comment: I used `column_stack` in my example, but didn't get the same results as you did. I would guess the difference is in the `w.rave1()...` line, but I don't quite understand what's happening there.

Comment: This will fail if the datatypes of the 1D arrays occupy a different number of bytes.

Answer (score 1):

To build on top of the chosen answer, you can make this process dynamic:

- You first loop over your arrays (which can be single columns)
- Then you loop over your columns to get the datatypes
- You create the empty array using those datatypes
- Then we repeat those loops to populate the array

**SETUP**

```py
# First, let's build a structured array
rows = [
    ("A", 1),
    ("B", 2),
    ("C", 3),
]
dtype = [
    ("letter", str, 1),
    ("number", int, 1),
]
arr = np.array(rows, dtype=dtype)

# Then, let's create a standalone column, of the same length:
rows = [
    1.0,
    2.0,
    3.0,
]
dtype = [
    ("float", float, 1)
]
new_col = np.array(rows, dtype=dtype)
```

**SOLVING THE PROBLEM**

```py
# Now, we dynamically create an empty array with the dtypes from our structured array and our new column:
dtypes = []
for array in [arr, new_col]:
    for name in array.dtype.names:
        dtype = (name, array[name].dtype)
        dtypes.append(dtype)
new_arr = np.empty(len(new_col), dtype=dtypes)

# Finally, put your data in the empty array:
for array in [arr, new_col]:
    for name in array.dtype.names:
        new_arr[name] = array[name]
```

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

You might want to look into numpy's record arrays for this use:

"Numpy provides powerful capabilities to create arrays of structs or records. These arrays permit one to manipulate the data by the structs or by fields of the struct."

Here's documentation on the record arrays:
http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.rec.html

You can use your variable names as the field names.

Answer (score -2):

Use a dictionary

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import numpy

w = {}
for key in ('x', 'y', 'z'):
    w[key] = np.random.randint(10, size=3)

print w
```