# Vectorize loop operation

Tags: python, numpy, vectorization, numpy-ndarray

I have a following operation working with a for loop. Could anyone suggest a way to vectorize the operation using numpy?

```
# rgb is a 3 channel image  
# points are computed using vector mult op (same size as rgb image)
# dtypes - rgb is uint8 and points is float
buffer = []
for v in range(rgb.shape[1]):
        for u in range(rgb.shape[0]):
            X,Y,Z = points[u,v,:]
            r,g,b = rgb[u,v,:] 
            buffer.append(struct.pack('ffffBBBBIII', X,Y,Z,0.0,
                                                     b,g,r,
                                                     255,0,0,0))
```

I want to condense the above op and get buffer. Any pointers would be helpful

Comment: What dtypes are your data?

Comment: `points` is `float` and `rgb` is `uint8`

Comment: try: `buffer = struct.pack('ffffBBBBIII', points[:,:,0],points[:,:,1],points[:,:,2],0.0,
                                                     rgb[:,:,0],rgb[:,:,1],rgb[:,:,2],
                                                     255,0,0,0)`, to see if `struct.pack` is vectorized

Comment: @Mstaino. Why would it be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a correspondence between struct types (C types) and numpy numerical types, this should be fairly simple. The documentation for struct is [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/struct.html#format-characters), while numpy's is [here](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.types.html). The relevant conversions are:

- `'f'` -> `np.single` (Python does not have the equivalent type)
- `'B'` -> `np.ubyte`
- `'I'` -> `np.uintc`

You can create the output as an array of values by making a [custom `dtype`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.dtypes.html#specifying-and-constructing-data-types), much like `struct` allows you to do:

```
dt = np.dtype([(c, np.single) for c in 'XYZW'] +
              [(c, np.ubyte) for c in 'RGBA'] +
              [('', np.intc, 3)])
```

The reason for creating separate fields for each channel (e.g. `[('X', np.single), ('Y', np.single), ...`) rather than creating a single field for all channels (e.g. `[('XYZW', np.single, 4), ...`) is that you want to be able to access arrays with uniform strides. The empty portion that you will not be assigning to can be a single block in each element: `('zeros', np.intc, 3)`.

You can have other dtypes that give you want results. For example, you can name your fields, or split them up into the individual channels. I would recommend doing that after you've written the output array, in a view, to simplify the processing.

Now that you have a dtype, make an array with it:

```
output = np.zeros(rgb.shape[:2], dtype=dt)
```

Now you can store the fields using the [`dt.fields`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.dtype.fields.html) attribute combined with [`output.setfield`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.setfield.html#numpy.ndarray.setfield):

```
for name, plane in zip('XYZ', np.moveaxis(points, -1, 0)):
    tp, offset, *_ = dt.fields[name]
    output.setfield(plane, tp, offset)

for name, plane in zip('RGB', np.moveaxis(rgb, -1, 0)):
    tp, offset, *_ = dt.fields[name]
    output.setfield(plane, tp, offset)

tp, offset, *_ = dt.fields['A']
output.setfield(255, tp, offset)
```

You can shorten to a single loop using [`itertoools.chain`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain):

```
from itertools import chain

for name, plane in zip('XYZRGBA', chain(np.moveaxis(points, -1, 0),
                                        np.moveaxis(rgb, -1, 0),
                                        [255])):
    tp, offset, *_ = dt.fields[name]
    output.setfield(plane, tp, offset)
```

Notice that the loop is not terribly expensive here. It only goes through seven iterations. Each element of the result is a buffer of the exact form your struct call was creating. You can discard the shape information by raveling the `output` array.

The result is an array with your custom dtype, equivalent the struct format spec to `'ffffBBBBIII'`. Each element canis a scalar that  be indexed by field name:

```
>>> output[0, 0]['W']
0.0
```

You can create alternate views into the array if you want, e.g., to group values into categories or something like that:

```
>>> dt2 = np.dtype([('p', np.single, 4), ('i', np.ubyte, 4), ('z', np.intc, 3)]
>>> output2 = output.view(dtype=dt2)
>>> output2[0, 0]['p']
array([0.501182 , 0.7935149, 0.9981835, 0.       ], dtype=float32)  # Random example data
```

This view does not copy the data, just interprets the existing buffer in a different way. Internally, the representation is still a packed version of what you were trying to achieve with your `struct`.

Answer (score 0):

I can think of this way:

```
def pack(points, rgb):
    X, Y, Z = points.transpose(2, 0, 1)
    r, g, b = rgb.transpose(2, 0, 1)
    rec = np.rec.fromarrays([X,Y,Z,r,g,b])
    def fn(point):
        X, Y, Z, r, g, b = point
        return struct.pack('ffffBBBBIII', X, Y, Z, 0.0, b, g, r, 255, 0, 0, 0)
    return np.vectorize(fn)(rec)
```

Comment: `np.vectorize` just runs a `for` loop. It does not compile your function.

Comment: Sure, vectorization in numpy is just `for` loops implemented in C, but still plenty faster than `for` loops in pure Python.

Comment: Exactly. And the name of `np.vectorize` is a bit misleading for that reason. It may remove some of the the looingp overhead, but incurs all the overhead of a *Python* function call for each element.

Answer (score -1):

You can use a [structured arrray](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.rec.html#module-numpy.doc.structured_arrays) with a dtype like

```
np.dtype([('point', 'f8', (4,)), ('rgb', 'uint8', (4,)), ('something', 'uint8', (4,))])
```

Afterwards you can call the method [ndarray.tobytes()](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.tobytes.html) of the array to get the buffer.

For initialization see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17456086/numpy-stacking-1d-arrays-into-structured-array) or [here](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.rec.html#indexing-and-assignment-to-structured-arrays).

Comment: How? The application is non-trivial